# magento - Add more options to Email Template dropdown list

Tags: php, magento, email-templates

I created a module, and I want to add some of my custom email template as option for the Email Template dropdown, say, "Create New Account" in `Admin > System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration`.

I tried to add a node in my custom module, like

```
<global>
    <template>
        <email>
            <customer_account_create_template>
                ...
            </customer_account_create_template>
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
```

PLEASE NOTE THAT I don't have my code when I wrote this, so `customer_account_create_template` might be incorrect, but I successfully REPLACED the option with my custom template.

The point is, I wanted to add it as another option, NOT to replace the default one. So, do you have any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Add at `config.xml` you should have your template declared inside the global tag and have a label on it.

```
<global>
    <template>
        <email>
            <custom_email_template translate="label" module="yourcustommodule">
                <label>Custom Email Template</label><!-- this should be shown in the config dropdown-->
                <file>mymodule/custom_email.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </custom_email_template>
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
```

system.xml field must match the name of the template with `_ instead of /`. In your case custom_email_template.

So your `system.xml` should look like this:

```
<sections>
    <custom ...>
       <groups>
           <email ....>
              <template>
                  <label>Email Template</label>
                  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                  <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                  <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                  <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                  <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
              </template>
           </email>
       </groups>
    </custom>
</sections>
```

And the `<default>` tag in `config.xml` should be

```
  <default>
        <custom>
          <email>
              <template1>custom_email_template1</template1>
              <template2>custom_email_template2</template2>
          </email>
        </custom> 
    </default>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. However, will it create a new dropdown in System Config? Because I didn't mean so, I want to add more options to existed config dropdown...

Comment: @alumi,welcome.you have to add a email template name in config.xml like `section_group_field`.

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you kindly update your answer to show me that?

Comment: i have already added template1,template2 etc you can add it like this. also change <custom_email_template1> <custom_email_template2> etc..